# Can't run Unit Tests In VS2012RC

Tags: mstest, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to run my unit tests for a Windows 8 Metro Class library i get the following 2 errors in the output window:

**Output:**

> ------ Run test started ------
>   Error : DEP3000 : Attempts to stop the application failed. This may cause the deployment to fail. 
>   App Packages may only be shutdown as part of a Visual Studio build operation.

```
Failed to activate Metro style unit test executor. Error: The application cannot be started. Try reinstalling the application to fix the problem.
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:01.2818304) ==========
```

**Other output:**

> ------ Discover test started ------
>   ========== Discover test finished: 7 found (0:00:00.6471091) ==========
>   ------ Run test started ------ Failed to activate Metro style unit test executor. Error: The application cannot be started. Try
>   reinstalling the application to fix the problem.
>   ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:02.0105835) ==========

Has anybody run into the problem?

Unit tests in other Win8 class librarys or apps works fine.

I think it's something with the solution. Yesterday everything went fine. I guess there was a Windows update, maybe that screwed things up?

Things i've tried:

- Uninstalled R#
- Reinstalled Visual Studio 2012 RC
- Tried unit tests in other class library (works)
- Tried unit tests in Windows 8 app (works)
- Cleaned / Rebuild solution
- Debug and Release Configuration
- Added another Test project to the solution and unload other project(works)

Techincal Specs:

- Visual Studio 2012 RC Version: 11.0.50522.1
- Windows 8 RC Build 8400
- 64 Bit OS
- Had resharper 7, Uninstalled it.

Comment: I've copied all my tests to another test project in the same solution, and now it works. Does anyone have an explanation ?

Comment: Do you have UnitTest settings file in the project?

Comment: @k0stya I don't see a test settings file in the project/solution but i think this is normal in winRT or vs2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but when I set the build configuration to x86 (Configuration Manager, Active Solution Platform) it suddenly works. If I set the configuration to AnyCPU or x64, I get the "Failed to execute..." error. 
I belive the test executer is a 32-bit application and it can not load a 64-bit library.

Comment: FYI: Does NOT work for me. Did the settings change and still have the error.