# Experiencing "DEP3000" error when trying to run WinRT unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, mstest

I am experience this strange error trying to run unit tests for WinRT from Visual Studio 2012.

> Error: DEP3000: Attempts to stop the application failed. This may
>   cause the deployment to fail. App Packages may only be shutdown as
>   part of a Visual Studio build operation

I don't understand at all what that could mean? I've tried restarting my computer and reinstalling developer license. How I reproduce it is I just create a new empty unit test project from the Visual Studio template. I don't touch the project at all. But, when I try to do Run Tests on it, it just says pending for a a while and then spits out that error

How do I fix this?

Specs: Windows 8 Enterprise 64bit, Visual Studio 2012 with Update 2

Also, I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439984/cant-run-unit-tests-in-vs2012rc) about VS2012RC, but the answer doesn't seem to apply. I've tried every configuration of this there is and nothing works past this error

Comment: Use Task Manager, Details tab.  See if you can kill the running instance of the unit test runner.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem when I applied VS upgrade2 AND used Resharper 7.1.1 to run the unittests. Turns out you need to upgrade Resharper to 7.1.3 -- or run the tests with the VS test explorer.

Comment: YUP, here's the blog post: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/04/resharper-713-is-available-for-visual-studio-2012-update-2/

Answer (score 0):

You can just try using XUnits App: 
https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/demooftheday/xunit-in-uwp

With this, test will run on XUnit's test app, not in VS Test Explorer.

In my unit test project's project.json

```
 {   
"dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.1.0",
        "xunit": "2.1.0",
        "xunit.runner.devices": "2.1.0"   },   "frameworks": {
        "uap10.0": { }   },   "runtimes": {
        "win10-arm": { },
        "win10-arm-aot": { },
        "win10-x86": { },
        "win10-x86-aot": { },
        "win10-x64": { },
        "win10-x64-aot": { }   } 
}
```

Then go to the XAML file in the unit test project named UnitTestapp.xaml and change it to

```
<ui:RunnerApplication
    x:Class="UnitTestProject1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UnitTestProject1"
    xmlns:ui="using:Xunit.Runners.UI"
    RequestedTheme="Light">
</ui:RunnerApplication>
```

And of course, in the code behind:

```
  sealed partial class App : RunnerApplication
  {
    protected override void OnInitializeRunner()
    {
      AddTestAssembly(GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
      InitializeRunner();
    }
    partial void InitializeRunner();
  }
```